# datatable.select("DateTime column")

Tags: datatable, columnsorting

I have a DataTable with a DateTime column.

First, I have a problem with sorting :

> DataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "CREATED_DATETIME asc";

it doesn't work properly,

Secondly, I have a problem with select :

> DataTable.Select("CREATED_DATETIME <" + FromDate +");

( FromDate is a radDatePicker control).

Answer (score 0):

As far as the getting the value from your RadDatePicker (Telerik?) I've not used this but it does look like you have more steps before that will work http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/mvc-getting-values-raddatepicker-raddateinput.html

What are the symptoms of the sort not working properly?